# Changing a comma delimited list into a paragraphed list in AppleScript

Tags: list, applescript

I need to change this type of list:

> 0001, 0002, 0003, etc

into this:

> 0001
>
> 0002
>
> 0003

etc

in Applescript.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`text item delimiters` is your friend

```
set theString to "0001, 0002, 0003"

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ", "}
set textItems to text items of theString
set text item delimiters to return
set theResult to textItems as text
set text item delimiters to TID

display dialog theResult buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
```

If you want extra empty lines like in your example add a second `return`

```
set text item delimiters to return & return
```

---

However if the source is already a list you can omit a few steps:

```
set theList to {"0001", "0002", "0003"}

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return & return}
set theResult to theList as text
set text item delimiters to TID

display dialog theResult buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
```